# Is there any textual evidence to support that Dumbledore was gay?

Tags: character-analysis, j-k-rowling, harry-potter, sexuality

JK Rowling [announced in 2007](http://www.the-leaky-cauldron.org/2007/10/20/j-k-rowling-at-carnegie-hall-reveals-dumbledore-is-gay-neville-marries-hannah-abbott-and-scores-more) to an audience at Carnegie Hall that Albus Dumbledore was in fact, gay and always had been...

> **Q:** Did Dumbledore, who believed in the prevailing power of love, ever fall in love himself?
>
> **JKR:** My truthful answer to you... **I always thought of Dumbledore as gay.** [ovation.] ... Dumbledore fell in love with Grindelwald, and that that added to his horror when Grindelwald showed himself to be what he was. To an extent, do we say it excused Dumbledore a little more because falling in love can blind us to an extent? But, he met someone as brilliant as he was, and rather like Bellatrix he was very drawn to this brilliant person, and horribly, terribly let down by him. Yeah, that's how I always saw Dumbledore. In fact, recently I was in a script read through for the sixth film, and they had Dumbledore saying a line to Harry early in the script saying I knew a girl once, whose hair... [laughter]. I had to write a little note in the margin and slide it along to the scriptwriter, **"Dumbledore's gay!" [laughter] "If I'd known it would make you so happy, I would have announced it years ago!"**

Was there ever any textual evidence in the *Harry Potter* novels that would have led a reader, especially the target readers, to believe this was the case?

Comment: Relevant, on Sci Fi SE: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/41282/59810  (Just to cross-reference them.)

Comment: Ah, JK ... she'll say any old crap to please the fans.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

In terms of *explicit* confirmation, the answer is a very solid **no**. At no point did any character, nor the omniscient narrator, identify Dumbledore's sexuality in simple terms.

### Signs and portents.

[Various](http://www.nytimes.com/2007/10/29/arts/29conn.html) writers have identified incidents and passages that might act as *subtle indicators* toward his sexuality. Note that all of these were spotted post-facto and some require a very ungenerous interpretation.

- **Dumbledore's love of knitting patterns, a typically feminine pre-occupation.**

  > *‘No, I was merely reading the Muggle magazines,’ said Dumbledore. **‘I
  >   do love knitting patterns.** Well, Harry, we have trespassed upon
  >   Horace’s hospitality quite long enough; I think it is time for us to
  >   leave.’*
  >
  > <sub><sup>Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince</sup></sub>
- **Dumbledore's [lack of a female love interest](https://www.theatlantic.com/daily-dish/archive/2007/10/dumbledore/224374/)**
- **Dumbledore's extravagant dress-sense**

  > *This younger Albus Dumbledore’s long hair and beard were auburn.
  >   Having reached their side of the street, **he strode off along the
  >   pavement, drawing many curious glances due to the flamboyantly cut
  >   suit of plum velvet that he was wearing.***
  >
  > <sub><sup>Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince</sup></sub>
- **Rita Skeeter's description of his relationship with Grindelwald (who we now learn was his lover). I've highlighted the smutty parts.**

  > *‘Oh, now, I’m glad you mentioned Grindelwald,’ says Skeeter, with a tantalising smile. ‘I’m afraid those who go dewy-eyed over Dumbledore’s spectacular victory must brace themselves for a bombshell – or perhaps a Dungbomb. **Very dirty business indeed.** All I’ll say is, don’t be so sure that there really was the spectacular duel of legend. After they’ve read my book, people may be forced to conclude that Grindelwald simply conjured a white handkerchief from the end of his wand and **came quietly!’***
  >
  > <sub><sup>Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows</sup></sub>
- **Rita Skeeter's description of his relationship with Harry Potter. I've highlighted the parts that suggest that he's a sexual deviant**

  > *‘Oh yes,’ says Skeeter, nodding briskly, ‘I devote an entire chapter to **the whole Potter–Dumbledore relationship. It’s been called
  >   unhealthy, even sinister.** Again, your readers will have to buy my
  >   book for the whole story, but there is no question that Dumbledore
  >   took **an unnatural interest in Potter from the word go**. Whether
  >   that was really in the boy’s best interests – well, we’ll see. It’s
  >   certainly an open secret that Potter has had **a most troubled
  >   adolescence.’***
  >
  > <sub><sup>Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows</sup></sub>
- **Aberforth's description of Dumbledore's relationship with Grindlewald**

  > *‘But after a few weeks of it, I’d had enough, I had. It was nearly
  >   time for me to go back to Hogwarts, **so I told ’em, both of ’em, face
  >   to face, like I am to you, now,’ and Aberforth looked down at Harry,
  >   and it took little imagination to see him as a teenager, wiry and
  >   angry, confronting his elder brother. ‘I told him, you’d better give
  >   it up, now.** You can’t move her, she’s in no fit state, you can’t
  >   take her with you, wherever it is you’re planning to go, when you’re
  >   making your clever speeches, trying to whip yourselves up a following.
  >   He didn’t like that,’ said Aberforth, and his eyes were briefly
  >   occluded by the firelight on the lenses of his glasses: they shone
  >   white and blind again. ‘Grindelwald didn’t like that at all. He got
  >   angry. **He told me what a stupid little boy I was, trying to stand in
  >   the way of him and my brilliant brother** … didn’t I understand, my
  >   poor sister wouldn’t have to be hidden once they’d changed the world,
  >   and led the wizards out of hiding, and taught the Muggles their place?*
  >
  > <sub><sup>Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows</sup></sub>
- **Dumbledore's own description of Grindelwald**

  > *‘Grindelwald. **You cannot imagine how his ideas caught me, Harry,
  >   inflamed me.** Muggles forced into subservience. We wizards triumphant.
  >   Grindelwald and I, the glorious young leaders of the revolution.*
  >
  > *‘Oh, I had a few scruples. I assuaged my conscience with empty words.
  >   It would all be for the greater good, and any harm done would be
  >   repaid a hundredfold in benefits for wizards. **Did I know, in my heart
  >   of hearts, what Gellert Grindelwald was? I think I did, but I closed
  >   my eyes.** If the plans we were making came to fruition, all my dreams
  >   would come true.*
  >
  > <sub><sup>Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows</sup></sub>
- **And of course, as the LA Times has stated, his *name* is a dead giveaway**

  > *"While the anagram to 'Tom Marvolo Riddle' is 'I am Lord
  >   Voldemort,' as my good friend pointed out, **'Albus Dumbledore' becomes
  >   'Male bods rule, bud!'"***
  >
  > <sub><sup>[Seven clues that 'Potter's' Dumbledore was gay](http://www.latimes.com/entertainment/movies/la-et-showbiz7-23oct23-story.html)</sup></sub>

Comment: Awesome answer usual. Many of those really stretch for the double meaning though. The last item I think clearly the most telling!

Comment: @Skooba - I do agree. The large problem with trying to read any sexual motivation into Dumbledore's character is that I'm reasonably confident that she didn't decide to make him gay until after she'd finished the books, whatever her protestations to the contrary. It's the same as her declaring that Hermione's race was never stated in the books (albeit in that case, she seemed to have forgotten that she did state it, repeatedly).

Comment: "She wants credit for being very up-to-date and politically correct -- but she didn't have the guts to put that supposed "fact" into the actual novels, knowing that it might hurt sales. ... When I have a gay character in my fiction, I say so right in the book. I don't wait until after it has had all its initial sales to mention it." - Orson Scott Card

Comment: Great answer. I'm having some trouble understanding what Aberforth's quote has to do with anything. He addressed "both of 'em" together because they were planning to conquer the Muggles together, not because they _were_ together, I think. I don't see how this quote furthers your point.

Comment: @Shokhet - I felt that he (Aberforth) was grumpy because Dumbledore was prioritising his relationship (with his gay lover) over taking care of his sister.

Comment: @Valorum okay. I guess that works

Comment: @Shokhet - It's tangential, I'll happily admit.

Comment: Many phrases are anagrams of many other phrases. "Albus Dumbledore" is also an anagram of "Loud Bramble Sued" - is that a dead giveaway that he likes to bring litigation against inanimate objects? And "Badder Bull Mouse" clearly makes him a rodent. While we're at it, "Tom Marvolo Riddle" <=> "Dammit, Drool Lover" <=> "Tom, A Mild Overlord"

Comment: Was the Babylon 5 reference in this answer deliberate?

Comment: @Randal'Thor - It was not. What did I say?

Comment: @Valorum "Signs and Portents". Maybe I just have Babylon 5 on the brain of late ...

Comment: @Randal'Thor - It's from the Bible, Isiah 8:18 - *Behold, I and the children whom the LORD has given me are for signs and wonders in Israel from the LORD of hosts, who dwells on Mount Zion*

Comment: The premise of this answer is good, but most of the evidence is really grasping at straws.

Comment: This is a good, and I feel, complete answer.  But here in Portland, and from my years in the UK, all of it (with exception of the last, epic one) would describe our run-of-the-mill hipsters.

Comment: @Pharap - I've tried to make the *straw-clutchingness* apparent in the answer. As I said above, the main problem is that in over a million words of text, JKR didn't see fit to mention his sexuality. That strongly suggests to me that he's been "[gay retconned](http://www.dorkly.com/post/73999/marvel-revealed-iceman-is-gay-and-it-makes-complete-sense)"

Comment: @Skooba - As I on another question, Card's attitudes on this matter could, in general, charitably be described as cruel.

Comment: My impression has generally been that Rowling really did always imagine him as gay, but that, bowing to the climate of the time, one that continues to exist today especially in regards to children's literature, she kept it limited to hints and subtext - a long practice with LBGT characters in literature. I wish she'd had a little more courage to write an explicitly gay character (which we also see her lacking today with the FB movies), but I do think it was always on her mind, and I think the implication was always there.

Comment: @Obie2.0 - That's certainly the impression that she wants to give *now*

Comment: I was saying that that was *my* belief. :) It may also be Rowling's too, if I'm lucky. One thing that pushes me in that direction, though, is that she revealed Dumbledore's sexuality something like three months after the publication of Deathly Hallows - soon enough that I doubt it was an effort to revive flagging fame, for example, or a change of heart (though I can believe that she wanted to get some sales before mentioning it, which again is a bit craven). Whether she had that in mind from 1997...who knows?

Comment: It was quite clear (to me, at least) at the time that I read it that Rita Skeeter was implying that Dumbledore was gay. Of course, I didn't believe anything that Rita said. But in retrospect, I think it's clear from that passage that Rowling had decided that Dumbledore was gay, at least by the time she wrote *Deathly Hallows*.

Comment: @PeterShor - The sly implication is that he's a paedophile (or that he at least exerts an unnatural and unhealthy influence on Harry Potter). I'm not sure the goal here was to imply that he's *gay* per se.

Comment: @Valorum: The implication—or at least, the one I was left with—is (1) he was Grindelwald's lover and (2) molested Harry Potter. So Rita is saying that he was ***both*** gay and a paedophile.

Comment: @Skooba Orson Scott Card is so full of it... Do we know details of Minerva McGonagall personal life? Or 90% of other "supporting cast"? We know that Snape is heterosexual because it influences the plot; some other wizards have families so one may make assumptions. Other than that, JKR may or may not have her own ideas about her characters that she just doesn't see fit to put down in black on white.

Comment: @IMil We know *a lot* about [McGonagall's personal life](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/professor-mcgonagall). Granted it also came after the fact.

Comment: @Skooba - Indeed. And for the record, I don't think there's any indication that she's *heterosexual* in the novels

Comment: I feel like this could do with the addition of the very first description of Dumbledore in the very first book. I mean, if you want to talk about flamboyant dressing - high heeled boots, anyone?